# Como abrir um executável que requer elevação via C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, permissões, processo

O código fornecido a seguir busca ser capaz de abrir um arquivo executável de forma que seja possível passar argumentos a ele uma vez que ele tenha sido aberto.

Para o código como ele está apresentado,  erro retornado é:

> Exceção sem tratamento: A operação solicitada requer elevação

Já quando configurado `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true`, o erro retornado é:

> Exceção sem tratamento: O objeto Process deve ter a
>   propriedade UseShellExecute definida como false para poder
>   redirecionar os fluxos de E/S.

Tendo isso em vista, excluindo-se os redirecionadores e por consequência, o argumento que seria passado ao executável, somente neste cenário é possível abrir o executável. Um primeiro resultado positivo, mas ainda não satisfatório.

```
private void CreatePorts(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start the child process.
    Process p = new Process();
    //Set parameters to redirect input/output from the application
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;            
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

    //Hide the application window
    //p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


    //Set the Application Path and Working to directory to the location of setupc.exe 
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\com0com";
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"setupc.exe";

    //Append command and flags and execute the process
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "list";
    p.Start();

    string output = "";

    output += p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + "\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine(output);    
    p.WaitForExit();            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segunda [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905713/221800):

```
if (!IsAdministrator()) {
    // Restart program and run as admin
    var exeName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exeName);
    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
    return;
}
private static bool IsAdministrator() {
    WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ProcessElevation.cs).

Mas sugeriram [algo aparentemente melhor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) em [outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133500/221800).